# Change Range Icon with Img Materialize CSS

Tags: css, html, range, materialize

can i change icon Range Slider from Materialize ?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, Paulie_D is right, if you would've researched about how to create range sliders from scratch then you would've customized it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dig deeper into the **materialize.css** file then you'll find this, on editing few things from this you can customize the slider-thumb.

Check W3Schools docs on **Range sliders**, you can customize by changing values like -
`border`, `height`, `width`, `border-radius` and many more. Don't forget to override these with the help of `!important`.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border-radius: 25% !important;
        background: #4826a6 !important;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .3s;
        transition: -webkit-box-shadow .3s;
        transition: box-shadow .3s;
        transition: box-shadow .3s, -webkit-box-shadow .3s;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        background-color: #26a69a;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        margin: -10px 0 0 0;
    }
```

**Customized Range Slider**

[image: Range - Slider]

[How to create Range Sliders - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp)